# Error con los acentos y ñ c++

Tags: c++

Estoy desarrollando una app Windows VCL Aplication c++ en RAD Studio 10.3. Tengo un fichero con los caption de los formularios en español. Cuando se los asignos que se visualizan los acentos y ñ presentan problemas remplazándoce por otros carateres.
Este es un ejemplo de mi fichero con los Caption:

```
....
std::map<AnsiString,AnsiString>caption;
caption["key1"] = "Ocurrió un error de acceso a la Base de Datos.";
caption["key2"] = "Cañon.";
...
```

En el Formulario por ejemplo:

```
....
Form1->Caption = caption["key1"];
Label1->Caption = caption["key2"];
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Si tu region no usa acentos, deberás usar `SetConsoleOutputCP`

Aqui hay una explicación
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-code-pages?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: no me aclara la duda la respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Si pretendes que tu aplicación sea **multi-plataforma** deberías usar `printf("%c", 164);` para imprimir la ñ y así con los acentos. Al utilizar la Win API que contiene métodos como `SetConsoleOutputCP` **no puedes portar** a otro OS el código.
Para evitar ir buscando los números en **ASCII** cada vez podrías hacer una **macro** con `#define` o con `const` para cada acento y la ñ (`#define ENYE 164 || const int ENYE = 164;`).

En tu caso sólo tienes que **reemplazar** todas las ñ y acentos con sus **ASCII** correspondiente. Pordrías realizar un programa externo que sea llamado por tu programa con `system(./programa); || system(.\programa.exe);` que se ocupe de iterar en los **caption**, que vaya transformando **temporalmente** cada carácter a `int`, y si ese `int` es el correspondiente a la ñ o acento que lo convierta a `int` directamente. Hay maneras **más optimas y rápidas** para hacer eso, pero espero que entiendas la idea.

Answer (score 0):

prueba cambiar el tipo de string.
Ej:
std::map<AnsiString,string>caption;
std::map<AnsiString,WideString>caption;

Answer (score 0):

No conozco los detalles de la tecnologia que estas usando. Parece que el conjunto de caracteres (ansi) que usas para el texto no es el que espera el formulario. Esto puede causar que sean interpretados erroneamente. Probablemente en el conjunto de caracteres que el formulario espera, los valores de los caracteres comunes (letras y numeros sin acentos) coinciden con los valores ANSI, por lo que se ven como deberian.
Intenta usar otro conjunto de caracteres en tu codigo. Uno de los mas comunes es UTF-8, asi que yo probaria con ese.

Otra idea: En windows creo que se usaban `wchar_t` para los textos. Esto lo haces prefijando la cadena con la letra L. `L"This is a wchar_t string"`. En la libreria estandar puedes encontrar `std::wstring`, que es como `std::string`, pero usa `wchar_t`.